# Create elements by looping a javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say we have an array of objects and we loop through it and create a div in every iteration.

How could we take the property `ol` (which is also an array of objects) in every iteration and create an `<ol>` inside the div for every object in it, with as many `<li>`'s as the number in the property `li`. Also, text inside the `li` should be the text of the property `title` so it should look like this:

[image]

I'm hitting my head to solve it but my noobness doesn't let me. I tried another loop of the `ol` object inside the outer loop, but I cant get it right.

```js
var array_of_objects = [{
  "name": "john",
  "job": "pilot",
  "email": "johnpilot@gmail.com",
  "ol": [{
    "li": 6,
    "title": "6 li's"
  }, {
    "li": 2,
    "title": "2 li's"
  }, {
    "li": 5,
    "title": "5 li's"
  }]
}, {
  "name": "mark",
  "job": "engineer",
  "email": "markengineer@gmail.com",
  "ol": [{
    "li": 2,
    "title": "2 li's"
  }, {
    "li": 7,
    "title": "7 li's"
  }, {
    "li": 2,
    "title": "2 li's"
  }, {
    "li": 1,
    "title": "1 li's"
  }]
}, {
  "name": "george",
  "job": "chef",
  "email": "georgechef@gmail.com",
  "ol": [{
    "li": 1,
    "title": "1 li's"
  }, {
    "li": 3,
    "title": "3 li's"
  }, {
    "li": 4,
    "title": "4 li's"
  }, {
    "li": 3,
    "title": "3 li's"
  }, {
    "li": 3,
    "title": "3 li's"
  }]
}]

function iterate(arr) {
  arr.forEach(i => {
    var name = i.name;
    var job = i.job;
    var email = i.email;
    var ol_li = i.ol_li;
    var str = `<div>
    <span>${name}</span>
    <span>${job}</span>
    <span>${email}</span>
    <span>ol's should be placed here</span>
    </div>`
    $("body").append(str);
  })
}

iterate(array_of_objects)
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: thin solid black;
  margin: 0.4em;
  padding: 0.2em;
}

span:not(:nth-child(4)) {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: thin solid red;
  margin: 0.2em;
  padding: 0.2em;
}

span:nth-child(4) {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0.4em;
  padding: 0.2em;
}

ol {
  border: thin solid blue;
  margin: 0.2em;
}

li {
  margin: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you require you can use `map()` to loop through the `ol` array of each object and create a HTML string which can be appended to the div you create.

Note the use of `fill()` in the example below to create the required number of `li` elements with the same content.

Also note that the same approach can be used to both tidy the code and improve performance as it means you only append to the DOM once when the loop completes, instead of within each loop iteration.

Try this:

```js
var array_of_objects = [{name:"john",job:"pilot",email:"johnpilot@gmail.com",ol:[{li:6,title:"6 li's"},{li:2,title:"2 li's"},{li:5,title:"5 li's"}]},{name:"mark",job:"engineer",email:"markengineer@gmail.com",ol:[{li:2,title:"2 li's"},{li:7,title:"7 li's"},{li:2,title:"2 li's"},{li:1,title:"1 li's"}]},{name:"george",job:"chef",email:"georgechef@gmail.com",ol:[{li:1,title:"1 li's"},{li:3,title:"3 li's"},{li:4,title:"4 li's"},{li:3,title:"3 li's"},{li:3,title:"3 li's"}]}];

function htmlFromData(arr) {
  return arr.map(obj => {
    let olHtml = obj.ol.map(ol => `<ol>${(new Array(ol.li)).fill(`<li>${ol.title}</li>`).join('')}</ol>`).join('');
    return `<div>
      <span>${obj.name}</span>
      <span>${obj.job}</span>
      <span>${obj.email}</span>
      <span>${olHtml}</span>
    </div>`    
  }).join('');
}

$("body").append(htmlFromData(array_of_objects));
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: thin solid black;
  margin: 0.4em;
  padding: 0.2em;
}

span:not(:nth-child(4)) {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: thin solid red;
  margin: 0.2em;
  padding: 0.2em;
}

span:nth-child(4) {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0.4em;
  padding: 0.2em;
}

ol {
  border: thin solid blue;
  margin: 0.2em;
}

li {
  margin: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time.
as i'm showing to my mockup picture,what i'm trying to achieve is to append an ol for every object inside the "ol" array,and every ol should have the amount of li's as the value in the property "li"

so for example,the first generated div should get 3 ol's,first ol with 6 li's,second ol with 2 li's and third old with 5 li's

Comment: Apologies - I corrected the answer for you, and improved the code.

Comment: Content of of li elements wasnt supposed to be of the same content,i made it that way for the sake of the example,in my application,its table cells instead of li's,and there is another array within the same object which contains the values of the cells,i hope i will be able to modify your code accordingly ! Cheers for the solution !

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do the trick :

- Map throw `ol` array and put single `li` item in a variable;
- Use `repeat()` function to print it in `ol` variable

```js
var array_of_objects = [
  {
    "name":"john",
    "job":"pilot",
    "email":"johnpilot@gmail.com",
    "ol":[
      {"li":6,"title":"6 li's"},
      {"li":2,"title":"2 li's"},
      {"li":5,"title":"5 li's"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name":"mark",
    "job":"engineer",
    "email":"markengineer@gmail.com",
    "ol":[
      {"li":2,"title":"2 li's"},
      {"li":7,"title":"7 li's"},
      {"li":2,"title":"2 li's"},
      {"li":1,"title":"1 li's"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name":"george",
    "job":"chef",
    "email":"georgechef@gmail.com",
    "ol":[
      {"li":1,"title":"1 li's"},
      {"li":3,"title":"3 li's"},
      {"li":4,"title":"4 li's"},
      {"li":3,"title":"3 li's"},
      {"li":3,"title":"3 li's"}
    ]
  }
]

  function iterate(arr){

  arr.forEach(i => {

  var name = i.name;
  var job = i.job;
  var email = i.email;
  var ol_li = i.ol;
  var list = "";
  var ol = ol_li.forEach(o=>{
     l = `<li>${o.title}</li>`
     list = `${list} <ol> ${l.repeat(o.li)} </ol>`

  })
  var str = `<div>
  <span>${name}</span>
  <span>${job}</span>
  <span>${email}</span>
  <span>${list}</ol>
  </div>`

  $("body").append(str);

  })

  }

  iterate(array_of_objects)
```

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  border:thin solid black;
  margin:0.4em;
  padding:0.2em;
}
span:not(:nth-child(4)){
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  border:thin solid red;
  margin:0.2em;
  padding:0.2em;
}
span:nth-child(4){
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  margin:0.4em;
  padding:0.2em;
}
ol{
  border:thin solid blue;
  margin:0.2em;
}
li{
  margin:0.2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```